# Хранение строк большого объема в winforms приложении

Tags: c#, winforms, text

У меня есть приложение `WinForms C#`. Мне нужно сохранить в нем (т.е. в `exe`-файле) текст размером, скажем, несколько сотен килобайт.
Примерно как в ресурсах сохраняются картинки. Какой самый удобный способ сделать это?
Сейчас храню в обычной `string` переменной, а это не совсем удобно

Comment: Закрывальщики, руки прочь от нормального вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если речь идёт о хранении данных непосредственно в самом приложении можно использовать [ресурсы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Хранить в них можно не только картинки, но и другие данные. Строки не исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Большие строковые данные можно хранить в текстовых файлах, которые, в свою очередь, помещаются в ресурсы. Делается это в Visual Studio достаточно просто:

- Устанавливаем свойство текстового файла "Build Action" в значение "Embedded Resource".
- Открываем редактор ресурсов (например, двойной клик на файле ресурсов).
- Перетягиваем текстовый файл из Project Explorer в редактор.
- Использование строковых данных в коде: Properties.Resources.имя_файла.